# Xcode 15 migration to string catalogs failed

Tags: xcode, localization, stringdictionary, string-catalog

I tried to migrate to the new localized string catalogs. But after this I can't build the app anymore. The error message stated something about an "old" .string file... but I checked all directories and there are no old .string files...

Anybody a hint how to go further?
[image]

And this is how the directories look after migration ...
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the error is referring to the presence of InfoPlist.strings, Localizable.strings and LocalizableDict.strings in Base.lproj directory.

I could be wrong, but if my memory serves me right, Base localizations for .strings files are not supported (it was intended only for things like Storyboards although I never really used it so I might be mistaken).

My guess is that the migrator only migrated the .strings/.stringsdict from actual language directories and as a result, Base.lproj was left untouched.

Try removing those files and see if the issue persists. Note that you might need to manually import the contents into your new Strings Catalogs if they weren't already covered by your development language.

Comment: Hi, many thanks for your reply... Yes, I tried that, but if I do it, "en" shows up as "not translated", which means that the keys are displayed, not the "translated" strings ... I think thats what you mean by "Note that you might need to manually import the contents into your new Strings Catalogs if they weren't already covered by your development language." ;-) ... Really want to avoid that... will wait and see what happens to this new feature. So far I will continue without the new catalog... opened the same thread on Apple / Developer and at least one "Apple staff" asked for more details...

Comment: @Hardy_Germany did you migrate successfully to strings catalog ? I have a huge Localizable.strings file and I don't want to manually add the strings from it to the new catalog.

Comment: Hi @JAHelia, no, but I haven't tried it since... I simply stick at the "tradional" way .. will give it again a try when I will add a new language ... Do you have the same issue? If you find a solution, I would be happy to get it :-)

Comment: I don't have issues, did. you try to right-click on the `localizable.strings` file and choose `Migrate to String Catalog` option from the menu ?

Comment: Yes, that's the way I tried... I think the main issue is that I have a "base" localization, an "English" one and a "German" ... and did set the development language to "English" .. so for english the base and the english localization exists in parallel  ... that might mixed up the build-in logic .. but as I said, will investigate deeper with the next languages, somewhen during this year ..